# How to make sticky footer in Xamarin forms across all pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, footer

Is that possible to add a sticky fix footer across all pages? when new page triggered, i want my header and footer remain same position without refreshing, only the main content which is places in the content view will change without the reload of header and footer.

Comment: Try ControlTemplates. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it with the default methods of changing page. To do that you would need to have only one page in the app and change only the view you want, without changing the whole page with PushAsync. Something like:

```
View centralView;
View CentralView
{
    get => centralView;
    set
    {
        if(centralView != null)
            (Content as Grid).Children.Remove(centralView);

        centralView = value;

        if(centralView != null)
            (Content as Grid).Children.Add(centralView, 0, 1);
    }
}

HeaderFooterPage()
{
    var pageContent = new Grid 
    {
        RowDefinitions =
        {
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) },
            new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) },
        }
    };

    centralView = new StackLayout(); // Initialize with the first view that you want

    pageContent.Children.Add(header, 0, 0);
    pageContent.Children.Add(footer, 0, 2);

    Content = pageContent;
}
```

And when you want to change the central view, just set CentralView to the view you want to change. Now you customize the code... Add animation when setting the central view, change properties/fields names to ones that makes sense in your project, etc.

Comment: The other option would be to include the same header and footer on each page and have the BindingContext for those set to the same instance of a ViewModel. Although, performance wise you're definitely better off using your suggestion and just switching out the Content.

Comment: Yeah, and besides that, he mentioned that he don't want the header and footer to reload